# pycmVectorError: Input vectors must have same length

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, confusion-matrix, pytorch-lightning

I want to display a Confusion Matrix, post-predictions.

Update:

```
INFO:root:len(y_actu): 21401
INFO:root:len(y_pred): 17522
```

**Set up model for predictions**

```py
def get_device():
    device = 'cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
    return device

def preprocess(input, preprocessor):
    r = []
    for i in input:
        x = preprocessor(i, padding='max_length', truncation=True)
        x = np.array(x['input_ids'])
        r.append(torch.tensor(x).unsqueeze(dim=0))
    result = torch.cat(r)
    return result

def predict_fn(input, model_artifacts):
    preprocessor, model, label_mapper = model_artifacts
    # Pre-process
    input_tensor = preprocess(input, preprocessor)
    # Copy input to gpu if available
    device = get_device()
    input_tensor = input_tensor.to(device=device)
    # Invoke
    classes = []
    probs = []
    softmax = torch.nn.Softmax()
    with torch.no_grad():
        output_tensors = model(input_tensor)[1]
        # Convert to probabilities
        for class_index, output_tensor in enumerate(output_tensors):
            output_tensor = softmax(output_tensor)
            prob, predictions = torch.max(output_tensor, dim=1)
            classes.append(label_mapper.reverse_map(predictions, class_index))
            probs.append(prob.tolist())

        classes = [c for c in zip(*classes)]
        probs = [c for c in zip(*probs)]
    return {'classes': classes, 'probabilities': probs}

device = get_device()
label_mapper = LabelMapper('classes.txt')
model = OntologyTaggerModel.load_from_checkpoint('last.ckpt', map_location=torch.device(device), from_checkpoint=True)
model_name = model.hparams['model_name']
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
DEFAULT_MODEL_MAX_LEN = 512
if tokenizer.model_max_length > DEFAULT_MODEL_MAX_LEN:
    tokenizer.model_max_length = DEFAULT_MODEL_MAX_LEN
model = model.to(device)
```

My defined variables: `y_actu` and `y_pred` are not the same length.

```py
from pycm import *

items = []
with open('val.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        r = line.strip().split('\t')
        items.append((r[-1], r[:-1]))
val = [item[0] for item in items]
lab = [item[1] for item in items]
size=200
classes = [] 
for pos in range(0, len(val), size):
    print(pos)
    preds = predict_fn(val[pos:pos + size], (tokenizer, model, label_mapper))
    classes += preds['classes']
indexes = [0,1]
cm = []
for index in indexes:
    y_actu= [l[index] for l in lab]
    y_pred = [c[index] for c in classes]
    cm.append(ConfusionMatrix(y_actu, y_pred, digit=3)) # ERROR !
```

Traceback (values increment by `200` because of line `size=200`):

```py
0
/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:29: UserWarning: Implicit dimension choice for softmax has been deprecated. Change the call to include dim=X as an argument.
200
400
600
800
1000
1200
1400
1600
1800
2000
2200
2400
2600
2800
3000
3200
3400
3600
3800
4000
4200
4400
4600
4800
5000
5200
5400
5600
5800
6000
6200
6400
6600
6800
7000
7200
7400
7600
7800
8000
8200
8400
8600
8800
9000
9200
9400
9600
9800
10000
10200
10400
10600
10800
11000
11200
11400
11600
11800
12000
12200
12400
12600
12800
13000
13200
13400
13600
13800
14000
14200
14400
14600
14800
15000
15200
15400
15600
15800
16000
16200
16400
16600
16800
17000
17200
17400
17600
17800
18000
18200
18400
18600
18800
19000
19200
19400
19600
19800
20000
20200
20400
20600
20800
21000
21200
21400
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
pycmVectorError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-e5ee206d8a81> in <module>
     19     y_actu= [l[index] for l in lab]
     20     y_pred = [c[index] for c in classes]
---> 21     cm.append(ConfusionMatrix(y_actu, y_pred, digit=3))

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pycm/pycm_obj.py in __init__(self, actual_vector, predict_vector, matrix, digit, threshold, file, sample_weight, transpose, classes)
     78         else:
     79             matrix_param = __obj_vector_handler__(
---> 80                 self, actual_vector, predict_vector, threshold, sample_weight, classes)
     81         if len(matrix_param[0]) < 2:
     82             raise pycmMatrixError(CLASS_NUMBER_ERROR)

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pycm/pycm_handler.py in __obj_vector_handler__(cm, actual_vector, predict_vector, threshold, sample_weight, classes)
    293         raise pycmVectorError(VECTOR_TYPE_ERROR)
    294     if len(actual_vector) != len(predict_vector):
--> 295         raise pycmVectorError(VECTOR_SIZE_ERROR)
    296     if len(actual_vector) == 0 or len(predict_vector) == 0:
    297         raise pycmVectorError(VECTOR_EMPTY_ERROR)

pycmVectorError: Input vectors must have same length
```

---

Note:

Predictions can be made in batch `predict_fn(input_list, (preprocessor, model, label_mapper))` where `input_list` is the list with input text data. For example, `predict_fn(['university of cambridge'], (preprocessor, model, label_mapper))`.

Please let me know if I should add anything else to post.

Comment: "*`y_actu` and `y_pred` are not the same length*" so, you know what the problem is... why do you think this difference is okay? Let us know why they are different.

Comment: Investigating this rn. We've met before! @Berriel